# My player keeps going down even though I told it to stop during KEYUP. Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keyup

I am working on my first game and every direction is working except down. When I stop pressing down my player keeps moving down. Every other direction stops during KeyUp.

```
while playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_Change = -10
                y_Change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_Change = 10
                y_Change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_Change = -10
                x_Change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_Change = 10
                x_Change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.type == \
                    pygame.K_DOWN:
                x_Change = 0
                y_Change = 0

    x += x_Change
    y += y_Change

    win.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, black, (x, y, 10, 10))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It's a typo `event.type == pygame.K_DOWN` has to be `event.key == pygame.K_DOWN` (focus on  `.type` -> `.key`)

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of: `event.type == pygame.K_DOWN` use `event.key == pygame.K_DOWN`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Where did the user go?

Comment: @AnnZen He probably went home. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPQ7fd00ORc